# Problems with relational operators in a varchar field in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this syntax sql who should pick up all the records in the table where the 'stock_ quantity' (Varchar Column) column is less than the 'minimum_amount' (Varchar Column) column:

> SELECT * FROM fazerem_xius WHERE stock_quantity < minimum_amount ORDER
>   BY name_products ASC

My syntax have a problem, if the column 'stock_quantity' stores the value 10, and column 'minimum_amount' stores the value 3, This record has been returned by the database, why is this happening and how to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to a number before comparing. For instance with a mathematical operation

```
SELECT * FROM fazerem_xius 
WHERE stock_quantity * 1 < minimum_amount * 1
ORDER BY name_products ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because string values are compared alphabetically. When you compare the string `10` to the string `3`, SQLite checks the first characters first. `1` is before `3` in the alphabet, that's why the result of `'10' < '3'` is true.

Use [`CAST()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) to cast them to numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM fazerem_xius WHERE CAST(stock_quantity AS INTEGER) < CAST(minimum_amount AS INTEGER) ORDER BY name_products ASC
```